# how to pass subdocumented array fields values

Tags: javascript, angularjs, node.js, mongodb

I have written a basic todo application using MEAN (Mongodb, Express, Angular, Node). Backend ie. Node.js part of application is working fine and have been verified using postman rest api client. But i am unable to pass the values taken from client to backend properly, may be my syntax is not correct and i am unable to figure it out.Also I am unable to get those subdocumented array field values to show on client side and everytime it returns an empty array field.

Backend part screenshot that it is working fine: 
[Screenshot 1](http://postimg.org/image/cjzfmmva5/a8b44fb5/)
[Screenshot 2](http://postimg.org/image/mhhjgm6y3/062b07fd/)

I have uploaded all my code to git public repository, you can download and try complete application [git repository](https://github.com/madhur0912/todo-app)

or here you can check below angular controller, html, & other related backend code.

post method:

```
api.post('/tasks', function (req, res) {

                var task = {};
                task.tasktype = req.body.tasktype;


                //category        : [req.body.category],



                task.taskinfo = [];
                for (var i = 0; i < req.body.taskInfo.length; i++) {
                        console.log(i);
                        var taskInfo = new TaskInfo(req.body.taskInfo[i]);
                        task.taskinfo.push(taskInfo);
                        console.log(task);
                }

                var taskObj = new Task(task);

                taskObj.save(function (err) {
                        if (err) {
                                res.send(err);
                                return;
                        }
                        res.json({
                                message: 'Task has been created'
                        })

                });
        });
```

task.js model

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var TaskInfoSchema = require("./taskinfo.js").TaskInfoSchema

var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

// Task schema
var taskSchema = mongoose.Schema({

 tasktype    : {type: String},
 createdon   : {type: Date, default: Date.now},
 updatedon   : {type: Date},
 taskinfo  : [TaskInfoSchema]  

});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Task', taskSchema); 

taskSchema.pre('save',function(next){
  this.updatedon = new Date()
  next();
});
```

taskinfo.js model:

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var Schema = mongoose.Schema;

var taskInfo = mongoose.Schema({

     isactive:{type:Boolean}, 
     taskobject:{type:String}, 
     taskdetails:{type:String}, 
     iscompleted:{type:Boolean}

    },{ _id :true,// false
     });


    var TaskInfo = mongoose.model('TaskInfo', taskInfo);
    module.exports.TaskInfo = TaskInfo;
    module.exports.TaskInfoSchema = taskInfo;
```

task controller:

```
$scope.addTask = function(){
    $http.post('/api/tasks',$scope.task).success(function(response){
        window.location.href='/#tasks';
    });
}
```

addtask html:

```
<h2 class="sub-header">Tasks</h2>
      <div class="table-responsive" ng-init="getTasks()">
        <table class="table table-striped">
          <thead>
            <tr>
              <th>#</th>
              <th>Task Type</th>
              <th>IsActive</th>
              <th>Task Object</th>
              <th>Task Details</th>
              <th>Is Completed</th>
              <th></th>
            </tr>
          </thead>
          <tbody>
            <tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
                <td>{{task._id}}</td>
                <td>{{task.tasktype}}</td>
                <td>{{task.taskInfo.isactive}}</td>
                <td>{{task.taskInfo.taskobject}}</td>
                <td>{{task.taskInfo.taskdetails}}</td>
                <td>{{task.taskInfo.iscompleted}}</td>
                <td><a href="#/tasks/details/{{task._id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a> <a href="#/tasks/edit/{{task._id}}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a> <button ng-click="deleteTask(task._id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
            </tr>
          </tbody>
        </table>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As it is written [here](http://mongoosejs.com/docs/subdocs.html):

> Sub-documents enjoy all the same features as normal documents. The
>   only difference is that they are not saved individually, they are
>   saved whenever their top-level parent document is saved.

```
var Parent = mongoose.model('Parent', parentSchema);
var parent = new Parent({ children: [{ name: 'Matt' }, { name: 'Sarah' }] })
parent.children[0].name = 'Matthew';
parent.save(callback);
```

So you should change thew way you save your task and taskinfo models. In your `api.js` file change:

```
task.tasktype = req.body.tasktype;


            //category        : [req.body.category],



            task.taskinfo = [];
            for (var i = 0; i < req.body.taskInfo.length; i++) {
                    console.log(i);
                    var taskInfo = new TaskInfo(req.body.taskInfo[i]);
                    task.taskinfo.push(taskInfo);
                    console.log(task);
            }

            var taskObj = new Task(task);
```

To:

```
task.tasktype = req.body.tasktype;

var taskObj = new Task(task);
taskObj.taskinfo = req.body.taskInfo;
```

And change your view:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <td>{{task._id}}</td>
    <td>{{task.tasktype}}</td>
    <td>{{task.taskInfo.isactive}}</td>
    <td>{{task.taskInfo.taskobject}}</td>
    <td>{{task.taskInfo.taskdetails}}</td>
    <td>{{task.taskInfo.iscompleted}}</td>
    <td><a href="#/tasks/details/{{task._id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a> <a href="#/tasks/edit/{{task._id}}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a> <button ng-click="deleteTask(task._id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

To:

```
<tr ng-repeat="task in tasks">
    <td>{{task._id}}</td>
    <td>{{task.tasktype}}</td>
    <td>{{task.taskinfo[0].isactive}}</td>
    <td>{{task.taskinfo[0].taskobject}}</td>
    <td>{{task.taskinfo[0].taskdetails}}</td>
    <td>{{task.taskinfo[0].iscompleted}}</td>
    <td><a href="#/tasks/details/{{task._id}}" class="btn btn-primary">Details</a> <a href="#/tasks/edit/{{task._id}}" class="btn btn-default">Edit</a> <button ng-click="deleteTask(task._id)" class="btn btn-danger">Delete</a></td>
</tr>
```

PS: Check your github repo for a pull-request.

Comment: Thank You so much sir for help, yes it works, i guess the problem was because the document was not getting saved in child doc.

Comment: Thanks, i will post more doubts if any,wishing you a good day :)

Comment: Try them by your own at first :) Cheers!